# Can someone help me make sense of this partition table?

Tags: partition

I inherited an older HPC which needs more storage. But I am way out of my depth here. To start with, I am trying to understand what I have in the first place. But I don't understand the output of `parted` when compared to `df`
Here's parted:

```
parted -l
Model: DELL PERC H710 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 146GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB  524MB  primary  ext4         boot
 2      525MB   146GB  146GB  primary               lvm


Model: DELL PERC H710 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1979GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1979GB  1979GB  primary               raid


Model: DELL PERC H710 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1979GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1979GB  1979GB  primary               raid


Model: DELL PERC H710 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 1979GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1979GB  1979GB  primary               raid


Model: DELL PERC H710 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 60.6GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary  ext4         boot
 2      525MB   60.6GB  60.0GB  primary  ext4


Model: DELL PERC H710 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 10.8TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  10.8TB  10.8TB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/vg_data-data: 3518GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  3518GB  3518GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/vg_data-home: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  2199GB  2199GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/vg_geneiousserver-lv_root: 141GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  141GB  141GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/vg_geneiousserver-lv_swap: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  4295MB  4295MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Seagate Expansion Desk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  4001GB  4001GB               primary


Model: Seagate Expansion Desk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdh: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  4001GB  4001GB               primary
```

and here is df:

```
df -h
Filesystem                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                               252G     0  252G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                  252G     0  252G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                  252G   43M  252G   1% /run
tmpfs                                  252G     0  252G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg_geneiousserver-lv_root  129G   15G  109G  12% /
/dev/sdf1                              9.8T  8.5T  836G  92% /home
/dev/sda1                              477M  332M  117M  75% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_data-data               3.2T  3.0T  240K 100% /home2
/dev/mapper/vg_data-home               2.0T  376G  1.6T  20% /var
tmpfs                                   51G   12K   51G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                                   51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1006
tmpfs                                   51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1028
tmpfs                                   51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1044
```

Answer (score 0):

Devices under `/dev/mapper` are mapped, i.e. several partitions (even form physically separated hard drives) are combined into one (or more) virtual partitions.

I think you should be able to figure out how and where your `sd[b-e,g-h]` are with `lsblk` and  `dmsetup deps -o /dev/mapper/<device-name>`. Maybe `dmsetup ls --tree` should be even better.

Comment: You show LVM - logical volumes on sda and RAID on sdb & sdc. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM RAID with 20.04
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices